# How do I get python to recognize my DLL file as import(able)

Tags: python, path

```
I ran into an error stating:
```

"ImportError: No module named 'pywintypes'", and after some reading around, I have discovered that the DLL for pywintypes is in C:\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\pywin_32_system32 in the form of a DLL file. Others have suggested adding the path to system path. I am new and have no clue how to do that. Any help is appreciated, I am running on python 3.5 32 bit. I installed "pywin32-220.win32-py3.5.exe"

Comment: Our [Help Section](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says, "understanding, writing, or debugging code" is offtopic here.

Answer (score -1):

try this in a new interpreter

C:\tools\python-2.7>python
Python 3.5 (default, july 15 2016, 09:23:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import sys
> > >       print '\n'.join(sys.path)

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\pyreadline-2.0_dev1-py3.5-win32.egg

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.8.0-py3.5-win32.egg

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\pillow-2.2.1-py3.5-win32.egg

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\pycairo-1.10.0-py5.5-win32.egg

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py3.5-win32.egg

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\pyzmq-14.0.1-py3.5-win32.egg

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\pygame-1.9.2a0-py3.5-win32.egg

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\sympy-0.7.3-py3.5-win32.egg

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\opencv_python-2.4.9-py3.5-win32.egg

C:\Windows\system32\python.zip

C:\tools\python-3.5\DLLs

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\plat-win

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\lib-tk

C:\tools\python-3.5

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\win32

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\lib

C:\tools\python-3.5\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

Comment: All i got was an "invalid syntax" error